# Position stop-loss set to zero after position is generated

Tags: mql5

I'm trying to write some modules for calculating trailing stop-loss in MQL5. The issue I'm having is that, whenever I attempt to retrieve the stop-loss for a position, I get a value of zero. I know the position doesn't have a stop-loss of zero because the journal shows that it was generated with a non-zero SL:

```
CS  0   12:59:55.438    Trade   2022.01.03 17:00:00   market sell 0.1 EURUSD sl: 1.13358 (1.13062 / 1.13063 / 1.13062)
CS  0   12:59:55.438    Trades  2022.01.03 17:00:00   deal #2 sell 0.1 EURUSD at 1.13062 done (based on order #2)
CS  0   12:59:55.438    Trade   2022.01.03 17:00:00   deal performed [#2 sell 0.1 EURUSD at 1.13062]
CS  0   12:59:55.438    Trade   2022.01.03 17:00:00   order performed sell 0.1 at 1.13062 [#2 sell 0.1 EURUSD at 1.13062]
```

Furthermore, when I check the stop-loss of the position immediately after I enter it, by doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < PositionsTotal(); i++) {
   
   if (PositionGetSymbol(i) != Symbol()) {
      continue;
   }
      
   ulong ticket = PositionGetTicket(i);
   PositionSelectByTicket(ticket);   
   PrintFormat("Position %d, Current SL: %f", ticket, PositionGetDouble(POSITION_SL));
}
```

This prints the following:

```
CS  0   12:59:55.439    test (EURUSD,H1)    2022.01.03 17:00:00   Position 2, Current SL: 1.133580
```

So, I can see that it's working, but only for the tick when the position was generated. Anytime after that, I get this:

```
CS  0   12:59:55.441    test (EURUSD,H1)    2022.01.03 18:00:00   Position 2, Current SL: 0.000000
```

So, what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this issue was caused by a completely separate problem. This is the code that was doing my trailing stop logic:

```
ExitResult Exit() {
   ExitResult result;
   result.Result = EXIT_RESULT_CONTINUE;
   
   if (!m_calculator.Enabled()) {
      return result;
   }
   
   for (int i = 0; i < PositionsTotal(); i++) {
      if (PositionGetSymbol(i) != Symbol()) {
         continue;
      }
      
      ulong ticket = PositionGetTicket(i);
      PositionSelectByTicket(ticket);
      
      double newSL;
      ENUM_POSITION_TYPE pType = (ENUM_POSITION_TYPE)PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE);
      int errCode = m_calculator.Calculate(i, pType, newSL);
      if (errCode != 0) {
         result.ErrorCode = errCode;
         result.Result = EXIT_RESULT_ERROR;
         break;
      }
      
      double existingSL = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_SL);
      
      if ((pType == POSITION_TYPE_BUY && newSL > existingSL) || (pType == POSITION_TYPE_SELL && newSL < existingSL)) {
         result.Order = CreateSltp(m_magic, ticket);
         result.Order.sl = newSL;
         result.Order.tp = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_TP);
         result.Result = EXIT_RESULT_EXIT;
         break;
      }
   }
   
   return result;
}
```

The issue here was that, if `newSL` was not modified by the call to `Calculate`, then it would contain its default value of 0. So, for any sell position, this would guarantee that the stop-loss would eventually be set to 0.

All I had to do was include a Boolean flag in `Calculate` that would be true if the rule modified `newSL` and false otherwise. This fixed the issue.